# Combine filtered or hidden cells

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, excel

### Purpose of the code:

I have 3 Excel files to deal with.
Those file have already been filtered or hidden because the content is very large. And I only need part of the content for every excel files.

I don't want to open every file and worksheets in order to copy the desired range.

I want to write a code to combine every filtered or hidden cells and put those cells to a brand new workbook.

### Steps of the code:

1. Combine every filtered or hidden cells of all worksheets for every excel files.
2. Create a new empty single-worksheet workbook.
3. Put all cells of Step 1 into Step 2.

### Problem of the code:

1. Running too slow

```
import openpyxl
import os
import glob


path = os.getcwd()
data=[]
x=input('name：') + '.xlsx'
target_xls = os.path.join(path,x)
for file in glob.glob(path+'\*.*'):
    if file.endswith((".xlsx")):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
        for sheet in wb.worksheets:
            for j in range(2, sheet.max_row+1 ):
                for i in range(1,sheet.max_column+1):
                    ihidden = sheet.row_dimensions[j].hidden  # Row Visibility True / False
                    svalue = sheet.cell(column=i,row=j).value
                    if ihidden == True:
                        shidden = "HIDDEN"
                    else:
                        shidden = "VISIBLE"
                        data.append(svalue)
WP= openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = WP.active
ws.title = "Sheet1"
x=sheet.max_column
new_list = [data[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(data), x)]
for elem in new_list:
    ws.append(elem)
WP.save(target_xls)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the program? What are you trying to do? Please add this information to your question, as it will make things easier for the answerers.

Comment: I wanna merge every cells of all excel file in the folder and generate a new workbook. Put those cells there. But I only wanna retrieve visible cells. The target file is already filtered or hidden. However, although my code works, it went very slow. I guess it's because I use too many for loops?

Comment: Since it's a multi-file operation it's never going to be very fast, but I'm sure it can be optimized. What kind of data size are we talking about anyway? Hundreds of files with hundreds of columns and thousands of rows?

Comment: I understand it's a multi-file operation. I tried to perform the code on three different excel files. (Total size: 4.5 MB). It turned out to take me 500 sec to complete. I think I would only use it to process some files no larger than 40 MB in total.

Comment: @Mast Could you please give me some advise?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Comment: You answered what the code is doing in a comment, could you please put that into the question body possibly with a little more detail? That would make this an excelent question.

Comment: @TobySpeight
Thank you! I have edit my post again.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Thank you! Now I have did that.

Comment: @MJ713 Thank you! I have explained that on my post.

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: providing a file with some sample data and its expected outcome can help too. It doesn't need to be as large as your original data, and can contain random numbers or text, but the operation should be the same

Comment: I'm feel very surprised for you all. Everyone can't understand what I meant exactly. The only thing you do is to change title and state concern precisely and yelling it's not clear enough. Do you guys(Engineers) really understand nothing about my concern? OK, no advise and no help. I would tell my friends and this forum is not a good place for someone who can speak or read the meaning. Ban my account and IP please. That's the only thing you nerds who only live on keyboards do.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I have figured it out the optimization problem without giving some sample data. haha